# Lifetime variable is the same for all instances of a sprite rather than reset when a new one is instantiated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm programming a game when the player dashes into a box it should break isntantiate broken pieces sprites which should disappear after a certain amount of time.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BrokenPieces : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update

```
public float moveSpeed = 3f;
private Vector3 moveDirection;

public float deceleration = 5f; 

public float lifetime = 3f;

public SpriteRenderer theSR;
public float fadeSpeed = 2.5f;


void Start()
{
    moveDirection.x = Random.Range(-moveSpeed, moveSpeed);
    moveDirection.y = Random.Range(-moveSpeed, moveSpeed);
}

// Update is called once per frame
async void Update()
{
    transform.position += moveDirection * Time.deltaTime;

    moveDirection = Lerp(moveDirection, Vector3.zero, deceleration * Time.deltaTime);

    lifetime -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(lifetime < 0)
    {
        theSR.color=new Color(theSR.color.r, theSR.color.g, theSR.color.b, Mathf.MoveTowards(theSR.color.a, 0f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime));

        if(theSR.color.a == 0f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        
    }
}
```

}

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Breakables : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[] brokenPieces;

```
public int maxPieces = 5;

public bool shouldDropItem;

public GameObject[] itemsToDrop;
public float itemDropPercent;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        if(PlayerController.instance.dashCounter > 0)
        {
        Destroy(gameObject);
         // show broken pieces
        int piecesToDrop = Random.Range(1, maxPieces);
       
        for(int i = 0; i < piecesToDrop; i++)
        {
            int randomPiece= Random.Range(0, brokenPieces.Length);

            Instantiate(brokenPieces[randomPiece], transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }

        // drop items
        if(shouldDropItem)
        {
            float dropChance = Random.Range(0f,100f);

            if(dropChance < itemDropPercent)
            {
                int randomItem = Random.Range(0, itemsToDrop.Length);

                Instantiate(itemsToDrop[randomItem], transform.position, transform.rotation);
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure it isn't using "static" anywhere in the real code? A static field would behave as you describe.

Comment: Static is not being used anywhere in the real code

Comment: Please show how you are starting this as this on its own is not enough

Comment: @BugFinder sorry im very new to this   check the OP i have added the script for the original box

Comment: So anything spawned has 3seconds to live therefore will die at the same time.

Comment: @BugFinder yes but iwould like it to break the box delete that box then instantiate broken pieces from that box, and then wait 3 second and remove them                             The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. this error comes up when i break the box

Comment: Right put a short delay on it so it can run the instantiate. Plus you can just hide the game object immediately so it looks gone.

Answer (score 1):

So your actual error has nothing todo with the timing.

> The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. this error comes up when i break the box

This happens because you destroy your object

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

and then after it is already destroyed try to access it's `transform.position`.

Simply either cache the position and rotation beforehand

```
var position = transform.position;
var rotation = transform.rotation;
Destroy(gameObject);
// show broken pieces
int piecesToDrop = Random.Range(0, maxPieces) + 1;
   
for(int i = 0; i < piecesToDrop; i++)
{
    int randomPiece= Random.Range(0, brokenPieces.Length);

    Instantiate(brokenPieces[randomPiece], position, rotation);
}
```

or make sure to put the

```
Destroy (gameObject);
```

at the bottom of your method so it isn't trying to access any of it's properties after destroying it.